# Programmatically change view path without views_alter

Tags: 7, views

I have a PHP script in which I want to set the path to a view.
For example on site1 I want the news to be at /news/index.html and on site2 I want the news to be at /blog/news/page/1.
The sites are sharing the modules folder so I cannot do this from the modules files. So I have a script in which I'm doing my initial setup for each website. Everything works perfect but the view path is not saved.

```
1. $view = views_get_view('news');
2. $view->display['page']->handler->options['options']['path'] = $my_path;
3. $view->save();
```

I also tried to use $view->override_path instead of line 2 but it's still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find the right way. The following code works great for me.

```
$view = views_get_view($view_name, TRUE);
$view->display['page']->display_options['path'] = $new_path;
views_save_view($view);
```